# HTTP and HTTPS with Spring Boot and JSF

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsf, undertow

I configured my app to use HTTP and HTTPS in spring boot and but I got an error on startup of Undertow. But Undertow start when I remove `undertowWebServerFactory` bean in Webconfig.java

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:555)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:283)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:358)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:309)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:588)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:601)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.DeploymentManagerHttpHandlerFactory$DeploymentManagerHandler.<init>(DeploymentManagerHttpHandlerFactory.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.DeploymentManagerHttpHandlerFactory.getHandler(DeploymentManagerHttpHandlerFactory.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowWebServer.createHttpHandler(UndertowWebServer.java:170)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServer.createHttpHandler(UndertowServletWebServer.java:72)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowWebServer.createUndertowServer(UndertowWebServer.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowWebServer.start(UndertowWebServer.java:114)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

`Webconfig.java`

```java
...

    @Value("${server.address}")
    private String serverAdress;

    @Value("${server.http.port}")
    private int httpPort;

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory undertowWebServerFactory() {
    UndertowServletWebServerFactory undertow = new UndertowServletWebServerFactory();
    undertow.addBuilderCustomizers(builder -> builder.addHttpListener(httpPort, serverAdress));

    return undertow;
    }
...
```

`application.properties`

```
...
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore
server.ssl.key-store-password=dummypwd
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.2
...
```

How can I do that ?